# CMake Linker Flags

Tags: c++, linux, gcc, cmake

I have a C++ code divided into 2 files image_desc_try.cpp, common.cpp and common.h. This code involves usage of Nvidia CUDA and NVidia NVInfer.

I could compile the entire code using the following with success.

```
 g++ -std=c++11 image_desc_try.cpp  common.cpp -I /usr/local/cuda/include -L /usr/local/cuda/lib64   -lcudart -lnvinfer -lnvparsers
```

Now, I am trying to do the same thing with CMake,

```
include_directories( "/usr/local/cuda/include" )
add_executable( desc_server
    common.cpp
    image_desc_try.cpp
)

target_link_libraries( desc_server
   ${catkin_LIBRARIES}
   /usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libnvinfer.so
   /usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libnvparsers.so
   /usr/local/cuda-10.0/targets/aarch64-linux/lib/libcudart.so
)
```

This is giving me linking errors:

```
/usr/lib/gcc/aarch64-linux-gnu/7/../../../aarch64-linux-gnu/libnvparsers.so: undefined reference to `getPluginRegistry'
/usr/lib/gcc/aarch64-linux-gnu/7/../../../aarch64-linux-gnu/libnvparsers.so: undefined reference to `getInferLibVersion'
/usr/lib/gcc/aarch64-linux-gnu/7/../../../aarch64-linux-gnu/libnvparsers.so: undefined reference to `getLogger'
/usr/lib/gcc/aarch64-linux-gnu/7/../../../aarch64-linux-gnu/libnvparsers.so: undefined reference to `nvinfer1::utils::reshapeWeights(nvinfer1::Weights const&, int const*, int const*, void*, int)'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
tx2_whole_image_desc_server/CMakeFiles/desc_server.dir/build.make:157: recipe for target '/home/dji/catkin_ws/devel/lib/tx2_whole_image_desc_server/desc_server' failed
make[2]: *** [/home/dji/catkin_ws/devel/lib/tx2_whole_image_desc_server/desc_server] Error 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:1578: recipe for target 'tx2_whole_image_desc_server/CMakeFiles/desc_server.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [tx2_whole_image_desc_server/CMakeFiles/desc_server.dir/all] Error 2
Makefile:140: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

How to fix this?

Comment: I don't have possibility to verify this, but I think that you have problem with the order the libraries are provided to linker. Try to switch the order of `nvinfer` and `nvparsers`. You can also put the cudart before both libnv* files.

Comment: Alternatively, just to be sure, you could link all libraries again after `libcudart`. Btw. you should just `target_link_libraries(desc_server -I /usr/local/cuda/include cudart nvinfer nvparsers)`. Specifying full path to `.so` files for linking is strange, I don't know if cmake parses it.

Comment: You could use the [`FindTensorRT.cmake`](https://github.com/NVIDIA/tensorrt-laboratory/blob/master/cmake/FindTensorRT.cmake) file to import targets properly